# How to extract those elements in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract the "Abstract" and the "Title" as shown in the photo below. However I can't extract the title and I tried to extract the tag "Abstract" but it didn't work.

```
String html = "http://example.com/";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("Abstract").first();
```

[image]

Comment: `Abstract` is not a tag in the sample html you provided. So obviously it won't work.

Comment: so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Element title = doc.select("FONT[size=+1]").first();

Element abstractParagraph = doc.select("CENTER:has(b:containsOwn(Abstract)) + p").first();
```